# Android studio said Resource ID #0x0 but i can't find the wrong

Tags: android

I'm a novice, and when I run the app, I am getting the following error.Please help me find out what is wrong. If you find any other errors or irregularities in this code, please help me to correct them.

```
Process: com.example.openlab_projectayh, PID: 2881
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:237)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2281)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1175)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
    at com.example.openlab_projectayh.xinxiadpater.getView(xinxifragment.java:87)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2405)
    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1297)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1414)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:452)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
   `
```

Here is the java code.I write a fragment.

```
public class xinxifragment extends Fragment {
private List<xinxi> nameList =new ArrayList<>();
xinxifragment(){}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wode_scrollview, container, false);
    ListView listView = view.findViewById(R.id.wode_listivew);
    initxinxi();
    xinxiadpater adapter = new xinxiadpater(getActivity(),R.layout.wode,nameList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}
public void initxinxi(){
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        xinxi mayijinfu = new xinxi("蚂蚁金服",R.id.dingdan);
        nameList.add(mayijinfu);
        xinxi shangjiafuwu = new xinxi("商家服务",R.id.faxian);
        nameList.add(shangjiafuwu);
        xinxi zhangdan = new xinxi("账单",R.id.dingdan);
        nameList.add(zhangdan);
        xinxi zongzichan = new xinxi("总资产",R.id.faxian);
        nameList.add(zongzichan);
        xinxi yue= new xinxi("余额",R.id.dingdan);
        nameList.add(yue);
        xinxi yuebao = new xinxi("余额宝",R.id.dingdan);
        nameList.add(yuebao);
        xinxi yinhangka = new xinxi("银行卡",R.id.dingdan);
        nameList.add(yinhangka);
        xinxi kefu = new xinxi("客服",R.id.dingdan);
        nameList.add(kefu);
    }
}   
class xinxiadpater extends ArrayAdapter<xinxi> {
    private Context context;
    private int resourceId;
    public xinxiadpater( Context context, int resourceId,List<xinxi> objects) {
        super(context, resourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        final xinxi name =getItem(position);
        View view;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(convertView == null){
            view =  LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(resourceId, parent,false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.textView = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            viewHolder.imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            viewHolder.xian = view.findViewById(R.id.xian);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
            view = convertView;
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.textView.setText(name.getName());
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(name.getImageId());
        viewHolder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context,name.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        viewHolder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context,name.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
class ViewHolder{
    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;
    View xian;
}
```

Maybe my mistake was stupid, but this project is important to me.

Comment: Whare these values R.id.dingdan can you please put up your xml files ?

Comment: name.getName() or name.getImageId() is returning 0
put a log in those getters and check the result. you are not providing any image or name for your xinxi class.